# Opengl low FPS when looking certain direction

Tags: opengl

I'm drawing surface composed of thousands of cubes. However when I'm looking in positive Z direction - that's where the light is, I get low fps and artifacts. 
This is how it looks when I'm looking in negative Z direction: 
[image: 1]
This is how it looks when I'm looking in positive Z direction, also drops fps noticeably:
[image: 1]

Comment: Did you implement some sort of culling? How do you render the cubes when they are touching? Low fps usually indicate a lot of calculations, which could happen if you do not reduce the vertex count when possible.

Comment: I have enabled back face culling. Cubes are rendered when touching as they are when they're single.

Comment: How exactly do the artifacts look?

Comment: You can see that in the second picture, it's not so obvious, but there are certainly wrinkles happening

Comment: That might be caused due to edges of two cubes next to each other.

Comment: An idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: How are you rendering your cubes? glBegin/glEnd? (very slow) or Vertex Buffer Objects? (fast) perhaps even something else?

Comment: YOu might want to investigate voxels.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably dependent of the order in which your cubes are rendered. That would explain why there is a difference between looking +Z or -Z. When rendering back to front, EVERY fragment of every cube is rendered. When rendering front to back with depth test, most fragments will be discarded. As for the artefacts you are seeing, could be Z-fighting, but that's a long shot.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any other way to turn on front to back rendering other than manual solution?

Comment: There are multiple ways to optimize rendering. It really depends of what is the REAL application of your code ( I'm guessing you don't really want to use several thousands of cubes only to draw a floor ). But in that particular case, not to render occluded faces comes to mind ( occlusion query, back face culling, sorting, render only one big sphere... ). We would need more details to help you further. But I think you can already try those. Hope this helps

Comment: @user1760770: OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a drawing API. It draws things in the order you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

How bad is this dip in performance? If you do a Z-only pre-pass of your geometry, skipping writes to the color buffer (and using a very simple pass-through fragment shader) you can improve performance greatly in situations where you have poorly-ordered/unsorted geometry and are fill-rate limited. This only helps when you are doing complicated fragment processing, however; it introduces twice the vertex transform overhead since you basically draw everything twice. Your situation could be either vertex or fragment bound, since composing surfaces of cubes is not exactly the most efficient way of rendering large planar surfaces.

My other suggestion, since you mention rendering a scene composed of "thousands of cubes" would be to implement something akin to voxel collapsing. All of your cubes in this example appear to be in the same plane, you can easily replace the faces for a collection of such cubes with fewer faces that combine adjacent cubes. Minecraft does this, by periodically re-meshing dynamically updated portions of the scene using a greedy meshing algorithm.

Of course, spatial partitioning is another issue, but I assume you already have some sort of system in-place?

Comment: Yes, I do. Problem I had in original post was as Jean-Simon Brochu suggested with back to front rendering performance. I've already changed that and it works fine. Thanks for your insight though.